# How can I take a browser to their password protected folder using a form where the browser inputs the folder name?

Tags: javascript

I have set up some password protected folders where clients can view protected files.
I need some login script that will ask the client to enter their ID.
The ID is the same as the folder name and the input should take the client to their folder.
This is where they have to enter their credentials to access the folder.
Looked around for ages but couldn't find anything???

Comment: How did you set up the protection? According to that, what you want may or may not be possible.

Comment: Security with JavaScript? You using Node?

Comment: I set up the folder protection through cPanel. The script I'm trying to use serves no security function. It nearly is a "menu" so the user will get to his protected directory by entering his ID into a form. His ID is the name of the directory. The form then takes the user to the protected folder where he enters his login credentials. Sorry if this wasn't clear...

Answer (score 0):

If you can use jQuery, something like:

In your markup:

```
<form id="access-protected-folder">
    <label>Please enter your ID</label>
    <input type="text" name="id" id="protected-folder-id" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

In your javascript:

```
$(function(){
    $("#access-protected-folder").submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault(); // Stop the default form action

        var baseFolderUrl = '/protected-folders/' // Base url to your folders

        window.location = baseFolderUrl + $("#protected-folder-id").val();
    });

});
```

See example jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/exHYE/

Comment: Hi, this is what I'm looking for - thank you. Just one thing, rather than having the alert, why doesn't it actually go to the folder as this is my end-state...

Comment: The alert was just included to in the jsFiddle example to show how this would work, as you can't redirect there. In your live code, you should remove the alert, and just use the line starting with window.location.